# R: Merging data.frames with multiple conditions & multiple logical operators

Tags: r

Good Day Everyone,

I've come across a challenging problem, whereby I'd like to find an elegant approach to:

1. Combining two data.frames on:

   a. Two common variables; AND

   b. A Date variable i.e. If DATE >= START_DATE & DATE <= END_DATE; AND

   c. Combined Code/ID variable i.e. If CODE_X == CODE_ID | CODE_X == ID

Here is data.frame 1:

```
CODE_ID = c("A01", "A10", "E01", "C01", "T01")
ID = c("A", "A", "E", "C", "T")
DATE = c("2008-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2009-08-01", "2008-09-01", "2009-10-01")
TF_1 = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F")
D_VAR_1 = c("D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0102")

DF1 = data.frame(CODE_ID, ID, DATE, TF_1, D_VAR_1)
```

Here is data.frame 2:

```
CODE_X = c("A", "A10", "E", "C", "T01")
START_DATE = c("2008-07-01", "2009-07-01", "2009-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2009-07-01")
END_DATE= c("2009-06-30", "2010-06-30", "2010-06-30", "2009-06-30", "2010-06-30")
TF_2 = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F")
D_VAR_2 = c("D_0101", "D_0102", "D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0102")
NAME = c("ACCIDENT", "MISC ACCIDENT", "ENERGY", "CONSTRUCTION", "POLITICS")

DF2 = data.frame(CODE_X, START_DATE, END_DATE, TF_2, D_VAR_2, NAME)
```

My final data.frame 3 looks like this:

```
CODE_ID = c("A01", "A10", "E01", "C01", "T01")
ID = c("A", "A", "E", "C", "T")
DATE = c("2008-07-01", "2008-07-01", "2009-08-01", "2008-09-01", "2009-10-01")
TF_1 = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F")
D_VAR_1 = c("D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0101", "D_0102")
NAME = c("ACCIDENT", "MISC ACCIDENT", "ENERGY", "CONSTRUCTION", "POLITICS")

DF3 = data.frame(CODE_ID, ID, DATE, TF_1, D_VAR_1, NAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using non-equi update join from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_v1.12.4
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

DF1[DF2, on=.(CODE_ID=CODE_X, DATE>=START_DATE, DATE<=END_DATE), NAME := i.NAME]
DF1[DF2, on=.(ID=CODE_X, DATE>=START_DATE, DATE<=END_DATE), 
    NAME := fifelse(is.na(x.NAME), i.NAME, x.NAME)]
```

output:

```
   CODE_ID ID       DATE TF_1 D_VAR_1         NAME
1:     A01  A 2008-07-01    F  D_0101     ACCIDENT
2:     A10  A 2008-07-01    F  D_0101     ACCIDENT
3:     E01  E 2009-08-01    F  D_0101       ENERGY
4:     C01  C 2008-09-01    F  D_0101 CONSTRUCTION
5:     T01  T 2009-10-01    F  D_0102     POLITICS
```

Comment: The solution also worked as intended on the theoretical example, but what I liked most, was how fast it was able to work through my large dataset, without providing duplicates. Note: in the solution the 'fifelse' should read as 'ifelse'.

Comment: data.table version >= 1.12.4 has fifelse

Comment: oh gosh, my bad. I'm going to look it up right now! thank you for the new intel!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `sqldf` package. It will let you combine dataframes as if you were writing sql queries. Can help with more complicated joins.

```r
library(sqldf)


sqldf.Example <- sqldf('select DF1.*, DF2.NAME from DF1 join DF2 on (DF1.CODE_ID = DF2.CODE_X or DF1.ID = DF2.CODE_X) and DF1.DATE between DF2.START_DATE and DF2.END_DATE')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution it works on the theoretical example. On a large scale, when implemented, I end up getting duplicated observations, which I feel may be arising out of the (DF1.CODE_ID = DF2.CODE_X or DF1.ID = DF2.CODE_X), when implemented. I may need to change this to a priority order of CODE_ID first, and ID last. Any idea if SQLDF allows for IF statements to be implemented?